# OpenVPN use the Failover IP as out interface

Tags: iptables, vpn, openvpn, ufw

I have a VPS Server (hosted in OVH cloud) with Failover IP configured

```
$ nano /etc/network/interfaces
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# Source interfaces
# Please check /etc/network/interfaces.d before changing this file
# as interfaces may have been defined in /etc/network/interfaces.d
# See LP: #1262951
source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*.cfg

auto ens3:0
iface ens3:0 inet static
    address MY_FAILOVER_IP
    netmask 255.255.255.255

    # IPFO 1
    post-up /sbin/ifconfig ens3:0 MON_IP_FAILOVER netmask 255.255.255.255 broadcast MON_IP_FAILOVER
    pre-down /sbin/ifconfig ens3:0 down
```

I follow the [tuto of Digital Ocean](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-an-openvpn-server-on-ubuntu-16-04) to install OpenVpn on my server. It's work but now, I want that my out ip is not those of my server but those of my Failover IP.

So, I saw this cmd

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.8.0.0/8 ! -d 10.8.0.0/8 -j SNAT --to-source ipfailover
```

But, I didn't work, I have always my server ip

The step 8 of digitalocean "[Adjust the Server Networking Configuration](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-an-openvpn-server-on-ubuntu-16-04#adjust-the-ufw-rules-to-masquerade-client-connections)" We modified the UFW rules so, I tried to adapt it with my request, given it above:

```
$ nano /etc/ufw/before.rules

# START OPENVPN RULES
# NAT table rules
*nat
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
# Allow traffic from OpenVPN client to wlp11s0 (change to the interface you discovered!)
-A POSTROUTING -s 10.8.0.0/8 -o ens3 -j MASQUERADE
## I ADDED IN MORE :
-A POSTROUTING -s 10.8.0.0/8 ! -d 10.8.0.0/8 -j SNAT --to-source MON_IP_FAILOVER
COMMIT
# END OPENVPN RULES
```

But it doesn't work.

Can you help me ?
Thanks

Comment: Could you share more info? What you receive when try to connect with OpenVPN client? What you see when try to get access trough VPN tunnel, if connection is ok?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you bought the failover ip from OVH, your iptables rule would allow the system to fix the source address of the packets as far as the host OS is concerned (useful if you have firewall rules blocking other IPs/etc). What do you mean when you say it doesn't work? What are you trying to accomplish? If you're trying to set up load balancing and failover, do you have a separate physical interface? My guess is you should be able to ping the failover ip but you may not be able to specify what ip OVH uses for your outbound traffic, especially if it's over the same virtual interface. (I am assuming that you use an internal address within their network, which they then translate, please correct me if I'm mistaken.)

Answer (score 0):

`iptables -t nat -I POSTROUTING -s [VPN CLIENT IP] -j SNAT --to-source [FAILOVER IP]`

this one worked for me

Comment: Hi and welcome to serverfault. please can you provide a more detailed answer? for example by explaining why op configuration doesn't work?

Comment: what do you need to know